# how does the view and my controller "connect"

Tags: php, templates

I am following a mvc tutorial but i dont understand how and why my code does't work.

So i have a Controller like so.

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $formSent = false;

    if (isset($_POST['send'])){
        $formSent = true;
    }

    $this->view->setVars([
        'name' => 'Stefan',
        'formSent' => $formSent
    ]);
}
```

and my form which is located in views/index

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Forumlar</title>
</head>

<body>
 <form method="post" action="/index">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Vorname</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="vorname"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Nachname</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="nachname"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>PLZ</td>
            <td><input type="number" name="plz"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <button type="submit" name="send">Send</button>
 </form>
</body>

<?php
echo  $name;

if ($formSent){
    echo "Form is Sent!";
}
?>
```

To make my question more simple to understand and where my problem is.

So echoing $name, does output in this case "Stefan".
While anything that is done with the form doesn not work.

For example dumping _POST will be empty and my if formSent statement does not work.

So how exacltey do i "connect" these two or how does it work ?

Thank you.

EDIT: Here its waht it says after i send the form

> Object not found! The requested URL was not found on this server. The
>   link on the referring page seems to be wrong or outdated. Please
>   inform the author of that page about the error.
>
> If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
>
> Error 404

EDIT 2:

Yes i do thave this in my IndexController

```
protected $view;

public function setView(\Mvc\Library\View $view)
{
    $this->view = $view;
}
```

Comment: Try to change the form `method` to `POST`.

Comment: Hey i tried that i will add the error message. Even if its now post.

Comment: What is the tutorial? There is a lot of moving pieces that we aren't seeing.

Comment: Is your .htaccess setup for clean URLs? Do you have a front controller doing routing and passing this stuff along? How are you returning the response to the view? Etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To connect the view to controller, u need to load the view page in controller..

in controller,

public function index() {

```
$this->load->view('YOUR PAGE NAME IN VIEW FOLDER');
```

}